# How to calculate d-axis and q-axis inductance from line to line current?

Tags: brushless-dc-motor, inductance

I'm wondering how to calculate the d-axis and q-axis inductances for a BLDC motor given the line to line inductance L. My hunch is to use the Park and Clark transforms that are used for current, but I wanted to double check.

Comment: Why do you need those?

Comment: I am simulating a motor in MATLAB simulink, and the block requests Ld and Lq, though I only have the line to line L from the motor data sheet.

Comment: Well, the time constant would be the same. Not sure what else matters.

Comment: Well, we are concerned about the torque generation (and velocity and position) of the motor during Field Oriented Control of a PMSM. Perhaps I should ask this question on a different forum though? Not sure if it’s totally appropriate here

Comment: Strangly no one answered, there were several gentlemen here who are strong in motion control.

Comment: But i am not sure what is your concern. Torque would be just current times Ki, which is a constant that ia not directly related to inductance. Just a number that is measured on the motor.

Comment: Sorry for not following up sooner - message got buried in my emails.

The inductance does affect how much instantaneous current is flowing through the coils though - right? And some PMSM motors have different Lq and Ld values (per my research, this is the case for internally mounted permanent magnets on the rotor)

Comment: Interesting. 99% of motors i work with are DC Brushless, which essentially are very much the same. The control loops for Id and Iq are completely identical. Though i can't pretend to know all the cases, i have never even heard of different control loop parameters for those.

Comment: It depends on the motor type but for high torque inner or outer surface pole magnets with sine wave voltage controlled VFD with at least 8 levels for a pseudo-sine and perhaps 3 phases , this article uses the Lumped Parameter Magnetic Circuit Model https://www.mdpi.com/1996-1073/9/8/580/pdf

Comment: @GregoryKornblum I found a good resource from TI explaining the difference for the control parameters. Slide 12: https://e2e.ti.com/support/archive/motor/m/pdf_presentations/665547

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 Thanks for the resource! I'll look into it - seems like I'll have to get more insight into how my motor was constructed... looking like it'll be easiest to just measure the Ld and Lq